# MSXM2.DOMDocument instance creation interrupts execution flow

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, com, activex

When a `MSXML2.DOMDocument()` instance is created from .NET COM component, it allows the current method execution flow to be interrupted and let the other requests to execute on the same thread and when they are done it resumes the initial method that was interrupted. 
But the same observation is not seen when `MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument()` instance is created. In this case, method execution flow is not interrupted.

I know that `MSXML2.DOMDocument` is not a thread safe and `MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocumen`t is. But the above behavior with `MSXML2.DOMDocument()` seem strange. Am I missing something

You may use the sample application from the following [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah079drRi8VYiIBMfhxRaiiTMhwCSQ) to reproduce.

> MFCApplication -> ATL COM EXE -> .NET COM component.
>
> - .NET COM Component(dll):
>
>   - Start()=> Creates "MSXML2.DOMDocument" documents indefinetly, until "_stop" flag is set.
> - Stop () => Sets the flag "_stop" to true.
> - ATL COM EXE:
> - CreateCSCOMComponent()=> Creates .NET COM Component instance on COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED
> - Start() => Invokes Start() on .NET COM Component.
> - Stop() => Invokes Stop() on .NET COM Component.
> - MFCApplication:    * Button "Start ATLCOMEXE" : Creates an instance of ATLCOMObject instance in COINIT_MULTITHREADED, which start
>     ATLCOMEXE.    * ATLCOMObject->Start() => invokes
>     "ATLCOMObject->Start()" on a separate thread.    *
>     ATLCOMObject->Stop() => invokes "ATLCOMObject->Stop()" on a separate
>     thread.
>
> **Steps to reproduce**:
>
> 1) Open MFCApplication.
>
> 2) Run debugviewer to see
>   the traces
>
> 3) Click "Start ATLCOMEXE"
>
> 4) Click "ATLCOMObject->Start()"
>
> 5) Observe the logs in debugview that .NET COM object continuously
>   creates instances of "MSXML2.DOMDocument()" on the same thead.
>
> 6)
>   Click "ATLCOMObject->Stop()"(once or multiple times).
>
> 7) Observe the
>   logs in debugview that .NET COM object inturrupts the execution flow
>   of "Start" and executes "Stop()" on the same thread where "Start" was
>   executing.

The above behavior seems strange to me.

Now, if we replace the code in `Start()` method of .NET COM component, to create `MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument(`) instead of `MSXML2.DOMDocument()` and run the above steps again, we would not see the observation 7), which is expected at least from my little knowledge in COM.

So I wonder what is causing method execution flow interruption when `MSXML2.DOMDocument` is created?

Comment: Some windows functions, which perform a long running operation, or wait for an action to complete (like disk IO), may contain a so called windows message loop, which handles windows messages and makes the GUI more responsive. It sounds like the Methods in DOMDocument have this behavior. My guess is that the FreeThreadedDOMDocument is designed for use on a worker thread, where there would be no need to service the windows message queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your EXE server defines this in `stdafx.h` (probably added by VS wizards):

```
#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED
```

- So it means the exe server will initialize COM using `CoInitialize(NULL)`, which means the thread that will create the .NET object will be STA.
- .NET objects are by default marked "both", so they basically can live in STA or in MTA. So your .NET object will be STA.
- The DomDocument needs an STA.
- The free-threaded DomDocument needs an MTA. (it's not "both').

As a rule of thumb, an STA thread means COM messages (=method calls) for objects created in this thread are pumped by a COM-created message loop running in this thread.
If you run your own loop in that thread and never lets the COM message loop run, then no method calls will ever get to objects in this STA.

STA is a *feature* (often enabled by default w/o anyone noticed) that will make sure an object marked as such will not be called by random threads and crash.

In your loop, when you create STA instances, you implicitely let the COM loop run, so method calls (Stop) can work it through.
When you create FT DomDocument instances, the COM loop simply doesn't run and no method call get through.

You'll have to understand how COM threading works to make the best decision in your case.

With your sample, you can just change your exe code and comment _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED ([the default is _ATL_FREE_THREADED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t07f8b4.aspx))
In this case, everything will run in MTA (well, if you still use a non FT DomDocument, it will live on an STA).

note: CoInitialize(Ex) must be called by the thread owner. Once called, it's useless to call it again. You code has some useless CoInitializeEx around.

Comment: thanks for clarification. Does this mean when DOMDocument() instance is created, it would start a new message loop? which lets the messages(i.e Stop) waiting for processing will be processed and once the DOMDocument creation completes "Start" continues with the rest?. Does this cause two message loops running, one the primary message loop by COM EXE(which is STA) and one when DOMDocument instance is created?. Or DOMDocument() creation request will be posted back to message loop running by COM EXE.

Comment: If we want to block the current thread to not process any other message while DOMDocument instance is created, how to achieve this. In other words how to achieve the behavior seen when FreeThreadedDOMDocument is created for DOMDocument creation?

Comment: COM message loops are tied to threads. Think of it as one loop per STA thread.